# Create Dynamic UI with Drag and Drop in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript2.0, formio

I want to create Dynamic form using angular 7 by using drag and drop. And I need these controls within for the form to be built using drag and drop using functionality:-

1. Check Boxes
2. Multiple Headings
3. Sub Headings
4. Table + Formatted
5. Tables + Unformulated
6. Checkbox + text
7. Text Fields + formatted
8. Edit Texts
9. Formatted View including Texts
10. Radio Buttons

We will create our form by dragging and dropping these control onto our form. We need to store the created form JSON into the database.

I have tried using ngx-schema form in angular 7. But Its not providing all the functionality which I required. So please give me any suggestion to wrap up this all. Thanks

Comment: Hi Muhammed Naeem this was an big process for create. Dynamic form concept is available for form inputs like textbox, checkbox, radio btn, edit txts, labe Other things you need to add like this dynamic form way.

Comment: I have been refered some website for this concept. I will share to you. In Answer block. But i don't have time to all proper configurations

Comment: Karnan Muthukumar thanks for the suggestion. Actually I wanna create form using Drag and Drop i-e from available form input I will drag and drop them onto a section to create a new form. Because we have different UI for our form. Any suggestion for this? Thanks once agian.

Comment: Yes thats also available. First you will create dynamic form using this. I will update my answer for create drag and drop option

Comment: Ok I am implementing this so please update your Answer for drag and drop. Thanks

Comment: If my answer is useful to you. Then mark as answer..

Comment: can you please write the blog for drag and drop in this week?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example for you dynamic forms,In this example used material form

https://medium.com/@mail.bahurudeen/create-a-dynamic-form-with-configurable-fields-and-validations-using-angular-6-994db56834da

Dynamic form concept is available for form inputs like

- textbox,  checkbox,   radio btn,   edit text box,  button,  date

Output seems,

[image]

For Drag and drop,

https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview

You have to merge this two things in your project then only it will achieve.

Comment: I have found the library to implement drag and drop feature using angular 6. Its very simple and awesome.  There is no need to repeat yourself and get the things done from stratch. Here is the link to that  library. https://formio.github.io/angular-demo/#/forms/builder

Comment: @MuhammadNaeem You can just create a new answer to your own question. However, please do not attempt to *replace* an existing answer from someone else with your own solution (I voted against your edit request). Both answers can cohabitate, and it's more useful to the community.

Comment: @Pac0 ok  Thanks.